# TypeError: angular.element.cleanData is not a function

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-mocha, angular-mock

I'm getting the following error in my karma unit test when trying to use `inject()`

```
  Example
    ✗ should wait for promise to resolve and have a result
    Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

  ✗ "after each" hook for "should wait for promise to resolve and have a result"
    TypeError: angular.element.cleanData is not a function
        at Function.module.$$cleanup (base/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?aa216eb2339283c5ab5aa192023171aa202a2bbd:2776:23)
        at Context.module.$$afterEach (base/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?aa216eb2339283c5ab5aa192023171aa202a2bbd:2746:14)
```

Here is the code:

```
describe('Example', function() {
  var $q;
  var $rootScope;
  var fakePromise;

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _$rootScope_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

    fakePromise = function fakePromise(){
      var def = $q.defer();
      setTimeout(function(){
        def.resolve('foo');
      }, 100);

      return def.promise;
    };
  }));

  it('should wait for promise to resolve and have a result', function(){
    return fakePromise().should.eventually.equal('foo');
  });
});
```

I'm using angular and angular-mocks 1.5.3.

Here is my karma config:

```
  // Karma configuration
  // Generated on Tue Mar 29 2016 14:28:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)

  module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

      // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
      basePath: '',


      // frameworks to use
      // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
      frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'chai-as-promised', 'sinon'],


      // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
      files: [
        'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'app/bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js',
        'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'app/bower_components/x2js/xml2json.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'app/httpsnippet-browser/dist/restlet-angular-httpsnippet.js',
        'app/bower_components/highlightjs/highlight.pack.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-highlightjs/angular-highlightjs.js',
        'app/bower_components/marked/lib/marked.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-marked/angular-marked.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-pretty-xml/src/angular-pretty-xml.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'app/bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js',
        'app/bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-yaml.js',
        'app/bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js',
        'app/bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-searchbox.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-ui-ace/ui-ace.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-ui-validate/dist/validate.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-ui-uploader/dist/uploader.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-inview/angular-inview.js',
        'app/bower_components/ng-resize/index.js',
        'app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        'app/bower_components/js-yaml/dist/js-yaml.js',
        'app/bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js',
        'app/bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
        'app/bower_components/yaml-js/yaml.js',
        'app/bower_components/async/lib/async.js',
        'app/bower_components/traverse/traverse.js',
        'app/bower_components/path-loader/browser/path-loader.js',
        'app/bower_components/json-refs/browser/json-refs.js',
        'app/bower_components/lodash/lodash.js',
        'app/bower_components/spark-md5/spark-md5.js',
        'app/bower_components/swagger-converter/browser.js',
        'app/bower_components/z-schema/dist/ZSchema-browser-min.js',
        'app/bower_components/visionmedia-debug/dist/debug.js',
        'app/bower_components/swagger-tools/browser/swagger-tools.js',
        'app/bower_components/apply-diff/index.js',
        'app/bower_components/json-editor/dist/jsoneditor.js',
        'app/bower_components/schema-form/dist/schema-form.js',
        'app/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js',
        'app/bower_components/json-formatter/dist/json-formatter.js',
        'app/bower_components/raf/index.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-ui-layout/ui-layout.js',
        'app/bower_components/json-schema-view/dist/json-schema-view.js',
        'app/bower_components/objectpath/lib/ObjectPath.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-native-dragdrop/draganddrop.js',
        'app/bower_components/d3/d3.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
        'app/bower_components/json-schema-defaults/lib/defaults.js',
        'app/bower_components/tv4/tv4.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/schema-form.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/bootstrap-decorator.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js',
        'app/bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js',
        'app/bower_components/js-base64/base64.js',
        'app/bower_components/sway/browser/sway.js',
        'app/bower_components/ngInfiniteScroll/build/ng-infinite-scroll.js',
        'app/bower_components/validator-js/validator.min.js',
        'app/httpsnippet-browser/dist/restlet-angular-httpsnippet.js',
        'app/ace/theme-atom_dark.js',
        'app/core/**/*.js',
        'app/**/*UnitSpec.js'
      ],


      // list of files to exclude
      exclude: [
      ],


      // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
      // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
      preprocessors: {
        // '**/*.js': ['coverage']
      },


      // test results reporter to use
      // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
      // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
      // reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
      reporters: ['spec'],


      // web server port
      port: 9876,


      // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
      colors: true,


      // level of logging
      // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


      // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
      autoWatch: true,


      // start these browsers
      // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
      browsers: ['Chrome'],

      // // optionally, configure the reporter
      // coverageReporter: {
      //   type : 'html',
      //   dir : 'coverage/'
      // },

      // Continuous Integration mode
      // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
      singleRun: false,

      // Concurrency level
      // how many browser should be started simultaneous
      concurrency: Infinity
    })
  }
```

Comment: sorry, was cut-n-paste error. I re-pasted it

Comment: Thanks, what if you would remove the `return` from the `it()` function?

Comment: the first error goes away but still getting `TypeError: angular.element.cleanData is not a function`

Comment: Could you please post the karma and angular mocks version you are using?

Comment: And we would also need the karma config, I have a theory.

Comment: Why would you need to use a timeout in a test?

Comment: its just a fake promise to demonstrate that chai-as-promised works as expected.

Comment: @chovy could you remove one of the `angular.js` files you have inside `files` and see if it makes any difference? I think `angular-mocks` should be loaded after the `angular`..

Comment: removing the duplicate `angular.js` and also ensuring that all angular libs were using `1.4.x` fixed my problem. I had some using 1.3.15 and others 1.4.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

removing the duplicate `angular.js` and also ensuring that all angular libs were using `1.4.x` fixed my problem. I had some using `1.3.15` and others `1.4.7`

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and what fixed it to me was to load jquery in my tests:

```
 files: [
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
...
]
```

took the idea from [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14251#issuecomment-198276079) because we also use jQuery alongside Angular.

(Downgrading my Angular version from 1.5.3 to 1.5.0 also did the job but now with my solution I can use the latest Angular version...)

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Including jquery solved the problem for me. Thank you.

Comment: Why isn't this the top answer?

Comment: Thank you! Based on this suggestion, I ran `bower install jquery` and put this line in my specRunner.html file: `<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

using the same angular and angular-mocks version solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and what fixed it was the following:

Go to the `angular-mocks.js` file and replace:

```
angular.element.cleanData(cleanUpNodes);
```

with

```
if (angular.element.cleanData) angular.element.cleanData(cleanUpNodes);
```

It was suggested in this post: https://rafikitechnology.com/2016/04/26/fixed-issue-with-angular-and-angular-mocks-do-not-agree-jasmine-is-angry/

Comment: that's not really solving the problem though, that's just hiding the error. I'm assuming that function has some usefulness? If its not needed then it shouldn't be called and removed completely.

Comment: Jup this solution can cause out of memory errors [see here on in the bugreport](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14251#issuecomment-199521171)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same issue as https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14251 (the error message looks different depending on which browser you use for the Karma tests).
I downgraded my Angular version from 1.5.3 to 1.5.0 and the error was gone. I think we'll have to wait until it's fixed in a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I am working in a very old legacy application and my problem was two-part:

1. The version of jQuery included in the master page of the app was too
   old, so I needed to import a newer version before angular.
2. I also moved my jQuery UI include above the angular.js include (there is a bug that this used to be a problem and should be fixed in later versions of Angular).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, I fixed it by adding the jquery denpendency on the top before angular on karma's config file.

```
  files: [
  { pattern: 'libs/jquery/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', watched: false },
  { pattern: 'libs/angular/angular/angular.js', watched: false },
  .....]
```